# How to return null on many to many join within window partition

Tags: mysql

I am creating a many to many join based on date, and then running a partition based on the `user_id`. The problem is that I need there to be an entry for each date, even if there is no data.

`color_table`

[image]

`guess_table`

[image]

Desired output (join with partition over user)

[image]

The problem is that, because user 1 didn't guess on 10-26-2021 and user 2 didn't guess on 10-28-2021, the rows with `null` simply don't exist. And I need the rows to be present as I'm doing operations within the window based on the date, so I need to see every date for a user, even if there's no guess.

Here is the fiddle with the window function and join:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b9f7f9549a0793aa16335141d86b7352

Here is the call I'm trying:

```
select dayt, user, cnt, guess, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user ORDER BY dayt) AS rowi
from color_table 
left join guess_table 
on dayt = dait;
```

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056 for SQL related questions.

Comment: Use `left join`s instead and please read above comment.

Comment: Sorry, I had made this question before the fiddle. And Jorge, using `left join` doesn't yield the null rows that I need. That's because there may be other values that will match up with the date that are not from the user that didn't guess.

Comment: Is there a way to use `COALESCE` within a window partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need all the combinations of the rows of `color_table` with each user and you can do this with a `CROSS JOIN`.
Then do a `LEFT` join to `guess_table`:

```
SELECT c.dayt, u.user, c.cnt, g.guess, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY u.user ORDER BY c.dayt) AS rowi
FROM color_table c
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT user FROM guess_table) u
LEFT JOIN guess_table g
ON g.dait = c.dayt AND g.user = u.user;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=39c27b084eb717f0a9439082beba8432).

Comment: Thank you! Although your answer is simpler, what I'm using this on is bit more complex than the fiddle and this answer gave me some weird results. However, as I've presented the question, this works! I appreciate it!

Comment: Hey, so your solution helped me a great deal but I've encountered a more complex scenario that I have not been able to figure out. Could you please have a look at this new question I posted? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69732660/cross-joining-3-columns-and-need-to-eliminate-null-rows-if-null-across-certain-c

Answer (score 1):

Because the data you want to be shown does not exist for the left join / join operation you have to create it first. You do so by using a CROSS JOIN operation and then left joining with the existing tables:

```
select cj.dayt, cj.user, c2.cnt, 
       g2.guess, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cj.user ORDER BY dayt) AS rowi
from 
   (select distinct c.dayt, g.user 
      from color_table c cross join guess_table g) cj
   left join color_table c2 on c2.dayt = cj.dayt
   left join guess_table g2 on g2.dait = cj.dayt and g2.user = cj.user;
```

See it working here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1ee0ee72007d3d17e50beb990f6691c2

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Thank you @MikelG Although, you should use Forpas version (and mark his as accepted), it is simpler. I added too much joins. His version is way better specially performance wise. I'm happy with just the up vote :)

Comment: Ok I switched it as requested! Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Your solution helped me a great deal but I've encountered a more complex scenario that I have not been able to figure out. Could you please have a look at this new question I posted? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69732660/cross-joining-3-columns-and-need-to-eliminate-null-rows-if-null-across-certain-c

Comment: Hey @MikelG I looked it up today (yesterday I was off my computer) but I see that Forpas already answered it for you! So all good now :)